# How do I only select the rows where revision_id is beyond the currently active revision?

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table of revisions and I want to write a sqlserver query to select only the rows for each message_id that have a revision_id greater than the revision_id for the currently active revision (marked by the is_active field).

This query selects all the rows in the revision table but I want to modify it to only select revisions beyond each current revision for each message.

```
select 
    mr.revision_id, 
    mr.message_id, 
    mr.group_id, 
    mr.width, 
    mr.height, 
    convert(varchar(10), mr.expiration_date,101),
    mr.resource_type, 
    mr.created_date, 
    mr.CreatedBy, 
    (select ma.is_approved from message_approval as ma where message_revision_id = mr.revision_id), 
    mr.RevisedBy, 
    mr.revised_date, 
    mr.is_active
from message_revision as mr
```

Comment: Please provide data and output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT mr2.*
FROM message_revision as mr1, message_revision as mr2
WHERE mr1.message_id = mr2.message_id
AND mr1.is_active = true
AND m2.revision_id > mr1.revision_id
```

Comment: Perfect!

Slight modification though: SELECT mr2.*
FROM message_revision as mr1, message_revision as mr2
WHERE mr1.message_id = mr2.message_id
AND mr1.is_active = 1
AND mr2.revision_id > mr1.revision_id